Why does && make its left hand side not fail?
This script:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

(
  set -e
  idontexist
  echo "launch the missiles"
) &&  echo "no errors"

prints:
line 7: idontexist: command not found
launch the missiles
no errors

with gnu bash 5.2.
Why is that?
I was under the assumption that set -e would cause the idontexist line to fail with the failure bubbling out.

set -e doesn't have an effect when you're testing a command using if or the logical operators && and ||. It's in the documentation.

You don't have any pipelines, why is pipefail in the snippet?

Thank you! That was a leftover from trying out. I'll remove it for clarity

"I was under the assumption that set -e would do X" is wrong for almost all values of X.  https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105

Also see Bash Pitfalls #60 (set -euo pipefail).

If this weren't how bash behaved, any script using set -e could never make any use of if (since what good's a conditional that can never be false without causing your code to exit?). && and || are likewise flow-control operators; there wouldn't be any point to supporting them if only one exit status were possible without forcing an immediate exit.

(Which is all to say -- set -e and ERR traps and equivalents are all hopelessly broken; get in the habit of explicitly using || return and || exit, and checking for presence of same during code review).

From the man page:
              -e      Exit  immediately if a pipeline (which may consist of a single simple command), a
                      list, or a compound command (see SHELL GRAMMAR above), exits with a non-zero sta‐
                      tus.   The  shell  does not exit if the command that fails is part of the command
                      list immediately following a while or until keyword, part of the  test  following
                      the  if  or  elif reserved words, part of any command executed in a && or || list
                      except the command following the final && or ||, any command in  a  pipeline  but
                      the  last,  or if the command's return value is being inverted with !.  If a com‐
                      pound command other than a subshell returns a non-zero status because  a  command
                      failed  while  -e  was being ignored, the shell does not exit.  A trap on ERR, if
                      set, is executed before the shell exits.  This option applies to the shell  envi‐
                      ronment  and each subshell environment separately (see COMMAND EXECUTION ENVIRON‐
                      MENT above), and may cause subshells to exit before executing all the commands in
                      the subshell.

                      If  a  compound command or shell function executes in a context where -e is being
                      ignored, none of the commands executed within the compound  command  or  function
                      body  will be affected by the -e setting, even if -e is set and a command returns
                      a failure status.  If a compound command or shell function sets -e while  execut‐
                      ing in a context where -e is ignored, that setting will not have any effect until
                      the compound command or the command containing the function call completes.

In particular

If  a  compound command or shell function executes in a context where -e is being
ignored, none of the commands executed within the compound  command  or  function
body  will be affected by the -e setting, even if -e is set and a command returns
a failure status.


In https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer, note the section Answer Well-Asked Questions and the bullet point therein regarding questions that have "been asked and answered many times before".
